# How to call Objective C function in to Javascript

Tags: ios

I have developed a iOS app, now i want to convert this phonegap app,My question is: how can i create plugins for iOS files

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to create objective-C Class files subClass of CDVPlugin  in plugin folder that is .h file and .m file.
After that, Create your method declaration and implementation as

```
-(void)methodName:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
```

[image]

and Add Your plugin file to Cordova.plist file as

[image]

And At last call your method in javaScript file as

```
cordova.exec(success, error, "MyCustomPlugin", "methodName", arr);
```

here arr is parameters you will send along with method call.And success and error are method callbacks.For more information you can get reference from here.

[Add Plugin in ios PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html)

Comment: I have Written all the code in Objective C, how can i convert this in to plugin code

Comment: I have many objective C files then how can i change in to sub class of CDVPlugin files

Comment: just import CVDPlugin.h in your objective c file and change superclass name to CVDPlugin

Comment: cordova.exec(success, error, "MyCustomPlugin", "methodName", arr); this statement i have written in js file but how could i interact